# How to mock NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest in unit testing

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, ios8, nsurlconnection

I have a function in which i am calling a network call as,

```
func newtorkCall() {
    //some other code
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response:
        NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (data != nil) {
            //save the data in a variable temp
        }
    })
}
```

this is working fine and i am getting the data.

But i want to mock this NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest in unit testing so that i can hardcode the data and pass it to the variable temp in the source code and test it.

How can I do it?